Scylladb error LWT is not yet supported with tablets
i want to implement sequence in Scylladb so i created a table :
CREATE TABLE project.sequence (
 name ascii PRIMARY KEY,
 value bigint
);

Then i inserted a row:
INSERT INTO project.sequence (name,value) VALUES ('UID', 1000);

Now i just want to update sequence where name is 'UID' but i got a LWT error from Scylla.
UPDATE project.sequence SET value=? WHERE name='UID' IF value=?;

This is error :
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot use LightWeight Transactions for table project.sequence: LWT is not yet supported with tablets"

In fact, i get this error every where I use LWT (if condition) !!!! What is the problem ?

I'm guessing you're using Scylla OSS 6.0, which has Tablets enabled by default, and, as the error says, Tablets aren't compatible with LWT yet. If you need to use LWT, you should create a keyspace without Tablets by appending " AND tablets = {'enabled': false}" to the CREATE KEYSPACE.

Another idea is to use older Scylla version.

See Tablets limitations, including no support for LWT, in ScyllaDB 6.0 here: https://opensource.docs.scylladb.com/stable/architecture/tablets.html#limitations-and-unsupported-features

@PiotrSmaroń I suggest you make this into an answer, not a comment.
Please note that when you do create a keyspace in Scylla 6.0 with tablets enabled (which is the default), you are warned that you won't be able to use LWT. The warning also tells you what you can do (delete the keyspace and re-create it with tablets disabled). I guess this warning wasn't conspicuous enough - or you created the keyspace through code, not a manual command, and code doesn't notice warnings :-(

I'll summarize the comments made by Piotr and Tzach into an organized answer:
ScyllaDB 6.0 introduces a new replication mechanism, called "tablets", where tables are split into small pieces ("tablets") that can be more easily and efficiently moved between nodes compared to the previous "vnodes" implementation.
Tablets have a lot of interesting benefits and promise, but as a new feature, it also has some temporary limitations until all the creases are ironed out. These limitations are listed in this page. One of the features not currently supported in conjunction with tablets is LWT, as you noticed.
The "tablets" feature is per-keyspace, so although it is turned on by default on new keyspaces, you can easily create a keyspace without tablets (i.e., use the classic vnode implementation), and then tables created in this keyspace will not use tablets, and will support LWT as before.
Note that if you CREATE KEYSPACE with tablets turned on (which is the default on ScyllaDB 6.0), you will get the following warning message:

Tables in this keyspace will be replicated using tablets,
and will not support the CDC feature (issue #16317) and LWT
may suffer from issue #5251 more often. If you want to use
CDC or LWT, please drop this keyspace and re-create it
without tablets, by adding AND TABLETS = {'enabled': false}
to the CREATE KEYSPACE statement.");

This error message is slightly misleading - it's not just that "LWT may suffer" from such issue - at this stage we outright forbid LWT with tablets and those requests will be outright rejected. But the warning message is useful in that it tells you the exact syntax to disable tablets in the CREATE KEYSPACE command.
